# WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (SpringJPA) is already registered

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

the problem is the entity manager factory's(emf) name has been registered twice and my database is empty.
There is a similar question but the accepted solution did not apply.
In detail:

java project:

com.springJPA.domain

-Actels.java

-Adresse.java

-Region.java

-Ville.java

-Utilisateur.java
  ...

com.springJPA.service

-ActelsService.java

-AdresseService.java

-RegionService.java

-VilleService.java

-UtilisateurService.java
  ...

com.springJPA.util

-MyEntityManagerFactory.java

-TransactionAspect.java
  ...

com.springJPA.test

-Main.java

The error I am getting is this:

```
WARN: HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (SpringJPA) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:291)
    at com.springJPA.service.RegionService.getNomRegionParId(RegionService.java:77)
    at com.springJPA.service.RegionService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6e2c95bb.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:692)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterAdvice.java:42)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)
    at com.springJPA.service.RegionService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7a8af85e_4.getNomRegionParId(<generated>)
    at com.springJPA.test.Main.afficherNOM_REGION_PAR_ID(Main.java:68)
    at com.springJPA.test.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

Main.java:

```
package com.springJPA.test;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.springJPA.domain.Actels;
import com.springJPA.domain.Adresse;
import com.springJPA.domain.Region;
import com.springJPA.domain.Utilisateur;
import com.springJPA.domain.Ville;
import com.springJPA.service.ActelsService;
import com.springJPA.service.AdresseService;
import com.springJPA.service.RegionService;
import com.springJPA.service.UtilisateurService;
import com.springJPA.service.VillesService;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        UtilisateurService utlService = (UtilisateurService) context.getBean("utlService");
        AdresseService adrService = (AdresseService) context.getBean("adrService");
        RegionService rgService = (RegionService) context.getBean("rgService");
        VillesService villeService = (VillesService) context.getBean("villeService");
        ActelsService atlService = (ActelsService) context.getBean("atlService");

        createUTILISATEUR(utlService);
        createADRESSE(adrService);
        createREGION(rgService);
        createVILLE(villeService);
        createACTEL(atlService);
        afficherLISTE_REGION();
        afficherLISTE_VILLE();
        afficherNOM_REGION_PAR_ID(52);
        afficherNOM_REGION_PAR_NUM(10);
        afficherNOM_VILLE_PAR_NUM(10);
        afficherLISTE_ACTEL();
        afficherLISTE_ACTEL_PAR_REGION(52);

    }

    private static void afficherNOM_VILLE_PAR_NUM(int num_ville) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        RegionService rgService = (RegionService) context.getBean("rgService");

        System.out.println("Nom Ville par num: "+rgService.getNomVilleParNum(num_ville));
    }

    private static void afficherNOM_REGION_PAR_NUM(int num_region) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        RegionService rgService = (RegionService) context.getBean("rgService");

        System.out.println("Nom Region par num: "+rgService.getNomRegionParNum(num_region));
    }

    private static void afficherNOM_REGION_PAR_ID(int id_region) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        RegionService rgService = (RegionService) context.getBean("rgService");

        System.out.println("Nom Region par id: "+rgService.getNomRegionParId(id_region));
    }

    private static void afficherLISTE_ACTEL_PAR_REGION(int id_region) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        ActelsService atlService = (ActelsService) context.getBean("atlService");

        List<String> listeActelparRegion= atlService.listeActel(id_region);
         for(String e:listeActelparRegion) {
             System.out.println("Actel par region :"+e);
          }
    }

    private static void afficherLISTE_ACTEL() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        ActelsService atlService = (ActelsService) context.getBean("atlService");

        List<String> listeActel= atlService.listeActel();
         for(String e:listeActel) {
             System.out.println("Actel :"+e);
          }
    }

    private static void afficherLISTE_VILLE() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        RegionService rgService = (RegionService) context.getBean("rgService");

        List<String> listeVille= rgService.listeVille("region2");
          for(String e:listeVille) {
                 System.out.println("Ville :"+e);
              }
    }

    private static void afficherLISTE_REGION() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        RegionService rgService = (RegionService) context.getBean("rgService");

        List<String> listeRegion= rgService.listeRegion();
          for(String e:listeRegion) {
                 System.out.println("Region :"+e);
              }
    }

    private static void createUTILISATEUR(UtilisateurService utlService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        creatUtilisateur(utlService, 1, "user1", "user1", "user1");
        creatUtilisateur(utlService, 2, "user2", "user2", "user2");
        creatUtilisateur(utlService, 3, "user3", "user3", "user3");
        creatUtilisateur(utlService, 4, "user4", "user4", "user4");
        System.out.println("Utilisateur crée");
    }

    private static void creatUtilisateur(UtilisateurService utlService, int id_utilisateur, String nom, String nom_utilisateur, String motdepasse) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Utilisateur utilisateur = new Utilisateur();
        //utilisateur.setUtilisateur_id(id_utilisateur);
        utilisateur.setNom(nom);
        utilisateur.setNomUtilisateur(nom_utilisateur);
        utilisateur.setMotdepasse(motdepasse);

        utlService.ajoutUtilisateur(utilisateur);

    }

    private static void createADRESSE(AdresseService adrService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        createAdresse(adrService, 1,"kantawi", "Sousse", "Tunisie");
        System.out.println("Adresse crée");
    }

    private static void createAdresse(AdresseService adrService, int id_adresse, String rue, String ville, String pays) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Adresse adresse = new Adresse();
        //adresse.setId_adresse(id_adresse);
        adresse.setRue(rue);
        adresse.setVille(ville);
        adresse.setPays(pays);

        adrService.ajoutAdresse(adresse);
    }

    private static void createACTEL(ActelsService atlService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        createActel(atlService, 1, 1, "actel_borjlouzir", 0x002);
        createActel(atlService, 2, 1, "actel_ariana", 0x001);
        createActel(atlService, 3, 2, "actel_mjezelbeb", 0x004);
        createActel(atlService, 4, 2, "actel_beja", 0x003);
        createActel(atlService, 5, 3, "actel_ezzahra", 0x048);
        createActel(atlService, 6, 3, "actel_rades", 0x006);
        createActel(atlService, 7, 3, "actel_benarous", 0x005);
        createActel(atlService, 8, 4, "actel_mzbourguib", 0x008);
        createActel(atlService, 9, 5, "actel_bizerte", 0x007);
        createActel(atlService, 10, 6, "actel_gabessud",0x010);
        createActel(atlService, 11, 6, "actel_gabes",0x009);
        createActel(atlService, 12, 6, "actel_elhammat",0x011);
        createActel(atlService, 13, 7, "actel_gafsa",0x012);
        createActel(atlService, 14, 8, "actel_kairouan",0x013);
        createActel(atlService, 15, 8, "actel_baytelhekm",0x014);
        createActel(atlService, 16, 9, "actel_sbitla",0x016);
        createActel(atlService, 17, 9, "actel_kasserine",0x015);
        createActel(atlService, 18, 10, "actel_kebili",0x017);
        createActel(atlService, 19, 11, "actel_kef",0x018);
        createActel(atlService, 20, 12, "actel_ksarsaid",0x020);
        createActel(atlService, 21, 12, "actel_zouhour",0x021);
        createActel(atlService, 22, 12, "actel_manouba",0x019);
        createActel(atlService, 23, 13, "actel_medenine",0x021);
        createActel(atlService, 24, 13, "actel_zarzis",0x023);
        createActel(atlService, 25, 13, "actel_djerba",0x022);
        createActel(atlService, 26, 14, "actel_Moknine",0x025);
        createActel(atlService, 27, 14, "actel_ksarhlel",0x024);
        createActel(atlService, 28, 14, "actel_mounastir",0x023);
        createActel(atlService, 29, 14, "actel_jammel",0x025);
        createActel(atlService, 30, 15, "actel_nabeul",0x026);
        createActel(atlService, 31, 15, "actel_mztmime",0x028);
        createActel(atlService, 32, 15, "actel_hammamet",0x027);
        createActel(atlService, 33, 15, "actel_korba",0x028);
        createActel(atlService, 34, 16, "actel_sfax",0x029);
        createActel(atlService, 35, 16, "actel_sfaxjadida",0x030);
        createActel(atlService, 36, 16, "actel_sfaxsud",0x031);
        createActel(atlService, 37, 16, "actel_elbousten",0x033);
        createActel(atlService, 38, 16, "actel_sakitezzit",0x032);
        createActel(atlService, 39, 17, "actel_sidibouzid",0x034);
        createActel(atlService, 40, 18, "actel_siliana",0x035);
        createActel(atlService, 41, 19, "actel_mseken",0x041);
        createActel(atlService, 42, 19, "actel_khezama",0x038);
        createActel(atlService, 43, 19, "actel_bouhsina",0x039);
        createActel(atlService, 44, 19, "actel_kantaoui",0x040);
        createActel(atlService, 45, 20, "actel_jendouba",0x037);
        createActel(atlService, 46, 20, "actel_tabarka",0x036);
        createActel(atlService, 47, 21, "actel_tataouine",0x042);
        createActel(atlService, 48, 22, "actel_tozeur",0x052);
        createActel(atlService, 49, 23, "Actel_hached",0x043);
        createActel(atlService, 50, 23, "actel_menzeh",0x050);
        createActel(atlService, 51, 23, "actel_babassel  ",0x047);
        createActel(atlService, 52, 23, "actel_Goulette",0x049);
        createActel(atlService, 53, 23, "actel_khpacha",0x044);
        createActel(atlService, 54, 23, "actel_manar",0x046);
        createActel(atlService, 55, 23, "actel_naser",0x045);
        createActel(atlService, 56, 24, "actel_zaghouane",0x051);
        System.out.println("Actel crée");
    }

    private static void createVILLE(VillesService villeService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        createVille(villeService, 1, 1, "borjlouzir", 0x000, "rue", "RUE MUSTAPHA MOH", "R_Semiramis");
        createVille(villeService, 2, 1, "borjlouzir", 0x000, "rue", "Rue Abderrazek J", "R_El Ahmadi");
        createVille(villeService, 3, 1, "borjlouzir", 0x000, "rue", "Rue DE VARSOVIE", "R_NADA");
        createVille(villeService, 4, 1, "borjlouzir", 0x000, "rue", "Rue Jawhara", "R_Emma");
        createVille(villeService, 5, 2, "ariana", 0x000, "rue", "Rue Abderrahmen ", "R_MALEK");
        createVille(villeService, 6, 2, "ariana", 0x000, "rue", "Rue Belhassen", "R_les Reves");
        createVille(villeService, 7, 2, "ariana", 0x000, "rue", "Rue Fethi Zouhei", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 8, 2, "ariana", 0x000, "avenue", "Ave Taieb MHiri", "R_YASMINA");
        createVille(villeService, 9, 2, "ariana", 0x000, "avenue", "Ave Hédi Nouira", "R_les Jasmins");
        createVille(villeService, 10, 3, "mjezelbeb", 0x000, "rue", "Rue Abderrahmen", "R_E");
        createVille(villeService, 11, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_El Ahmadi");
        createVille(villeService, 12, 54, "manar", 0x000, "rue", "Rue de", "");
        createVille(villeService, 13, 43, "Kalaa_Essghi", 0x000, "rue", "Rue de", "");
        createVille(villeService, 14, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_MALEK");
        createVille(villeService, 15, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "Rue Abderrazek E", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 16, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 17, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 18, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 19, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 20, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 21, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 22, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 23, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 24, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 25, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 26, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 27, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 28, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 29, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 30, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 31, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 32, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        createVille(villeService, 33, 42, "kalaa_Kebira", 0x000, "rue", "RUE 1ER JUIN", "R_Ennour");
        System.out.println("Ville crée");
    }

    private static void createREGION(RegionService rgService) {
        createRegion(rgService, 1, "Ariana", 1);
        createRegion(rgService, 2, "Beja", 2);
        createRegion(rgService, 3, "BenArous", 3);
        createRegion(rgService, 4, "Bizerte", 4);
        createRegion(rgService, 5, "Gabes", 5);
        createRegion(rgService, 6, "Gafsa", 6);
        createRegion(rgService, 7, "Kairouan", 7);
        createRegion(rgService, 8, "Kasserine", 8);
        createRegion(rgService, 9, "Kebili", 9);
        createRegion(rgService, 10, "Kef", 10);
        createRegion(rgService, 11, "Manouba", 11);
        createRegion(rgService, 12, "Medenine", 12);
        createRegion(rgService, 13, "Monastir", 13);
        createRegion(rgService, 14, "Nabeul", 14);
        createRegion(rgService, 15, "Sfax", 15);
        createRegion(rgService, 16, "SidiBouzid", 16);
        createRegion(rgService, 17, "Siliana", 17);
        createRegion(rgService, 18, "Sousse", 18);
        createRegion(rgService, 19, "Tabarka", 19);
        createRegion(rgService, 20, "Tataouine", 20);
        createRegion(rgService, 21, "Tozeur", 21);
        createRegion(rgService, 22, "Tunis", 22);
        createRegion(rgService, 23, "Zaghouan",  23);
        System.out.println("Region crée");
    }

    private static void createRegion(RegionService rgService, int id_region,String nom_region, int num_region) {
        Region region = new Region();
        //region.setId_region(id_region);
        region.setNom_region(nom_region);
        region.setNum_region(num_region);
        rgService.ajoutRegion(region);

    }

    private static void createVille(VillesService villeService, int id_ville, int id_region, String nom_ville, int num_ville, String type_voie, String voie, String resedence){
        Ville ville = new Ville();
        //ville.setId_ville(id_ville);
        ville.setId_region(id_region);
        ville.setNom_ville(nom_ville);
        ville.setNum_ville(num_ville);
        ville.setType_voie(type_voie);
        ville.setVoie(voie);
        ville.setResedence(resedence);

        villeService.ajoutVille(ville);
    }

    private static void createActel(ActelsService atlService, int id_actels, int id_ville, String nom_actel, int num_actel){
        Actels actel = new Actels();
        //actel.setId_actels(id_actels);
        actel.setId_ville(id_ville);
        actel.setNomActels(nom_actel);
        actel.setNum_actel(num_actel);

        atlService.ajoutActel(actel);
    }

}
```

RegionService.java:

```
package com.springJPA.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.springJPA.domain.Region;
import com.springJPA.util.MyEntityManagerFactory;

@Component("rgService")
public class RegionService {
    @Autowired @Qualifier("myEMF")
    private MyEntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void ajoutRegion(Region region) {
        entityManager = emf.getEntityManager();
        entityManager.persist(region);
    }

    public void modifRegion(Region region) {
        entityManager = emf.getEntityManager();
        entityManager.merge(region);

    }

    /**
     * supprimerRegion
     * @param region
     */
    public void supprimerRegion(Region region) {
        entityManager = emf.getEntityManager();
        entityManager.remove(region);

    }

    /**
     * listeRegion
     * @return listeRegion
     */
    public List<String> listeRegion() {
        entityManager = emf.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select LOWER(e.nom_region) from Region e ORDER BY e.id_region ASC", String.class);
        List<String> results = query.getResultList();
        return results;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param nomRegion
     * @return listeVille
     */
    public List<String> listeVille(String nomRegion) {
        entityManager = emf.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select LOWER(e.ville) from Region e where e.nom_region = ?1 ORDER BY e.id_region ASC", String.class);
        query.setParameter("1", nomRegion);
        List<String> results = query.getResultList();
        return results;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param id_region
     * @return String
     */
    public String getNomRegionParId(int id_region) {
        entityManager = emf.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select LOWER(e.nom_region) from Region e where e.id_region = ?1", String.class);
        query.setParameter("1", id_region);
        String result = query.getSingleResult();
        return result;

    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param num_region
     * @return String
     */
    public String getNomRegionParNum(int num_region) {
        entityManager = emf.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select LOWER(e.nom_region) from Region e where e.num_region = ?1", String.class);
        query.setParameter("1", num_region);
        String result = query.getSingleResult();
        return result;

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param num_ville
     * @return String
     */
    public String getNomVilleParNum(int num_ville) {
        entityManager = emf.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager.createQuery("Select LOWER(e.ville) from Region e where e.num_ville = ?1", String.class);
        query.setParameter("1", num_ville);
        String result = query.getSingleResult();
        return result;

    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public MyEntityManagerFactory getEmf() {
        return emf;
    }

    public void setEmf(MyEntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }


}
```

application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springJPA.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springJPA.util"/>
<bean id="tr" class="com.springJPA.util.TransactionAspect">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEMF"/>
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.springJPA.service.AdresseService.*(..))" id="adrPC"/>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.springJPA.service.UtilisateurService.*(..))" id="utlPC"/>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.springJPA.service.RegionService.*(..))" id="rgPC"/>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.springJPA.service.VillesService.*(..))" id="villePC"/>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.springJPA.service.ActelsService.*(..))" id="actelPC"/>
    <aop:aspect ref="tr">
     <aop:before pointcut-ref="adrPC" method="begin"></aop:before>
     <aop:after pointcut-ref="adrPC" method="commit"></aop:after>

     <aop:before pointcut-ref="utlPC" method="begin"></aop:before>

     <aop:before pointcut-ref="rgPC" method="begin"></aop:before>
     <aop:after pointcut-ref="rgPC" method="commit"></aop:after>

     <aop:before pointcut-ref="villePC" method="begin"></aop:before>
     <aop:after pointcut-ref="villePC" method="commit"></aop:after>                 

     <aop:before pointcut-ref="actelPC" method="begin"></aop:before>
     <aop:after pointcut-ref="actelPC" method="commit"></aop:after>
    </aop:aspect>
 </aop:config>

</beans>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SpringJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Adresse</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Utilisateur</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Actels</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Couleurd</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Couleurt</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Distribution</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Etat</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Mise_instance</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Demande</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Positiont</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Reference</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Region</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Rg</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Sr</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Payement</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Transport</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Client</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Etat_demande</class>
    <class>com.springJPA.domain.Ville</class>
    <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.mysema.query.jpa.support.ExtendedOracleDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="appACTEL" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="appACTEL" />
    <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>       <aop:after pointcut-ref="utlPC" method="commit"></aop:after>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the right schema in the right database?

Comment: yes, it is the right schema. it was working fine. just i add some modification.